# Firebase Simple Login for LinkedIn

Tags: authentication, linkedin-api, firebase

Does anyone know if there is a LinkedIn Simple Login authentication for Firebase?

Something similar to the Facebook Simple Login for Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-facebook.html)

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no Simple Login provider for LinkedIn. The current Firbase Simple Login providers are:

- Facebook
- Twitter
- GitHub
- Persona
- Email/Password

[Firebase is integrated with Singly](https://singly.com/docs/firebase), who has LinkedIn and dozens of other providers. You might want to look into their services. However, they seem to be pivoting to a health care service instead of an OAuth integration platform, so you may wish to consider their future before committing.

Also see Andrew Lee's comment on this answer; Custom Login is a great way to go if you're looking specifically for LinkedIn.

Comment: Don't forget you can auth any way you want using Custom Login:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html